# I can add images with HTML but not CSS when the file path is definitely correct

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm trying to learn how to add an image with CSS only.

The image path is correct when I put it into my html using an `<img>` tag.

```
<img src="C:\img\blue_lines_background.jpg" />
```

The image appears, but when I use the same image path with CSS nothing happens.

I've seriously tried looking through every tag to try to find an answer. I've tried using different images and checked the properties to see if I had it blocked from view or if there was a security setting blocking it from use, but that wouldn't make sense if it works in HTML but not CSS.

It's the same exact file path in CSS as the one that worked in HTML.

I don't know why it isn't showing up.

CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    }

    h1#logo {
    background: url(C:\img\blue_lines_background.jpg);
    }
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    
    <!-- Normalize.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">

    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="google.css">

    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
    <![endif]-->

        <title>Fake Google</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">+You</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Gmail</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apps</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sign in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <h1 id="logo">Google</h1>

        <form>
            <input type="search">
            <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
            <input type="submit" value="I'm Feelin' Lucky">
        </form>

        <p><small>Google.us offered in <a href="">Fran&ccedil;ais</a></small></p>

        <footer>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Advertising</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Terms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Use Google.com</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </footer>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In CSS images don't have a width & height you should set your width and height manually in css. Also with your current markup Google would appear over the top of your image.

Comment: Okay so I deleted the "Google" text in the <h1> tag and added a random height and width for image within CSS file but it's still not showing up. Do I need to make the height and width to scale with the image?

Comment: You should read through the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: Notable - The background attribute is just "shorthand" for a bunch of other properties https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add the double quotes in the url() thing:

```
h1#logo {
   background: url("C:\img\blue_lines_background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I added the quotes and still nothing, added a height and width but still nothing.

Comment: This is incorrect quotes are not required in paths. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()

Answer (score -1):

I think (and I may be wrong, CSS isn't what I do most of my work in) that you can't use CSS to put in images other than background. CSS controls design rather than content. I think that HTML has a "logo" function that you can use, though I've personally never used it. Just try looking up "HTML logo tag" on Google and there should be a plethora of information there. If I'm wrong, feel free to correct me. This could definitely be a learning experience for me, too.

Comment: This is although trying to be helpful - incorrect you can add content in css using the content property, although not indented for core content mechanics it is possible.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

You are correct in the rest of your sentiments about usage.

This probably should be a comment instead of an answer since it doesn't actually solve any problem.

Comment: Thanks. I don't work much in CSS so that was a very minimally educated assumption on my part. You learn something new every day!